# String manipulation macro: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘,’ token

Tags: c, types, macros, polymorphism

I am trying to write a macro which will automate definition of polymorphic types achived by composition and function pointers.

I don't really know a lot about macro string manipulation. This is how I imagine the macro definition:

```
#define INSTANCE(ret, name, ...) ret (*name)(__VA_ARGS__);
#define TYPE(name, ...) typedef struct { Object base; __VA_ARGS__ } name
```

It may be used like following:

```
TYPE(A,
     INSTANCE(void, print_name, void),
     INSTANCE(void, set_id, char *, id)
);
```

And generated structure, in this example, should be:

```
typedef struct {
    Object base;
    void (*print_name)(void);
    void (*set_id)(char *);
} A;
```

In my implementation compiler returns error:

```
main.c:14:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘,’ token
   14 |      INSTANCE(void, print_name, void),
      |                                      ^
```

Did it mean that "arguments to function pointer evaluation" fails? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your `TYPE` macro cannot work as presently imagined because the members of a structure (that have different types specified must be separated by semicolons (`;`), but your macro will produce commas in their place.

Comment: After each semicolon there will be a comma generated, right?

Comment: I put semicolon at the end of the INSTANCE definition:
`#define INSTANCE(ret, name, ...) ret (*name)(__VA_ARGS__);`

Comment: I change the invocation to: `TYPE(A, INSTANCE(void, print_name, void) INSTANCE(void, set_id, char *id));`

This seem to work now. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your question consider having a "vtable" outside the struct instead. Otherwise you'll be dragging the function pointers around for every instance of the object, which wastes memory and also exposes the functions to the caller for changing.

Comment: That's what I have in my code @Lundin. Good notice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, you have too many commas in your source code.
So either remove them manually or modify your macros to do it for you:

```
#define REMOVECOMMA2(\
    a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20,...) \
    a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a15 a16 a17 a18 a19 a20 
#define REMOVECOMMA(...) REMOVECOMMA2(__VA_ARGS__,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)

#define INSTANCE(ret, name, ...) ret (*name)(REMOVECOMMA(__VA_ARGS__));
#define TYPE(name, ...) typedef struct { Object base; REMOVECOMMA(__VA_ARGS__) } name

TYPE(A,
    INSTANCE(void, print_name, void),
    INSTANCE(void, set_id, char *, id)
);
```

Please note that the macros can only remove a limited numbers of commas (in above example: 19)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a excess comma in your use of the macro.  You need to use it like:

```
TYPE(A,
     INSTANCE(void, print_name, void)   /* no comma here */
     INSTANCE(void, set_id, char *, id)
);
```

It would probably be cleaner/clearer to NOT use `...` in the definition of `TYPE`:

```
#define TYPE(name, BODY) typedef struct { Object base; BODY } name
```

That way you'll get the error more directly in the parsing of the `TYPE` macro.  You could also remove the `;` from the end of the expansion of `INSTANCE` and use it like:

```
TYPE(A,
     INSTANCE(void, print_name, void);
     INSTANCE(void, set_id, char *, id);
);
```

which might be clearer.